# Referenciar um valor do array dentro dele mesmo

Tags: php

Tenho uma função dentro de uma classe, e dentro dessa função eu tenho o seguinte vetor:

```
$compra = [

    "produto" => "Chocolate Nestle",
    "preco"   => 5.5,
    "frete"   => 1.5,
    "total"   => $compra['preco'] + $compra['frete']

];
```

Eu preciso fazer a soma do preco e do frete dentro do próprio vetor, eu uso o `var_dump` para me mostrar o resultado e acontece esse erro:

> var_dump($compra);

```
NOTICE Undefined variable: compra on line number 10

NOTICE Undefined variable: compra on line number 10
array(4) { ["produto"]=> string(16) "Chocolate Nestle" ["preco"]=> float(5.5) ["frete"]=> float(1.5) ["total"]=> int(0) }
```

linha 10 é a linha que faz a soma

Comment: Possível até é, mas qual seria a utilidade disso? Supondo que o "preço" e "frete" venham de uma variável dinâmica, você não pode simplesmente somar estas tuas variáveis no "total"?

Comment: Já tentou **$compra.preco + $compra.frete** ?

Answer (score 0):

Poderia por gentileza tentar o código a seguir ?

```
$compra = [

    "produto" => "Chocolate Nestle",
    "preco"   => 5.5,
    "frete"   => 1.5,
    "total"   => $compra.preco + $compra.frete
];
```

Ou então :

```
$compra = [

    "produto" => "Chocolate Nestle",
    "preco"   => 5.5,
    "frete"   => 1.5,
    "total"   => ["preco"] + ["frete"]
];
```